# Dart: Why can't generic types be restricted with "implements"?

Tags: dart

Why is it invalid in Dart to restrict generic types with "implements", like so:

```dart
class MyClass<T implements MyInterface> {
...
}
```

Is this just a limitation of the language?  Or is there a reason why it doesn't make sense?

Dart permits restriction using "extends", but there are cases where a class is already extending another class and you just want to add a separate interface that you can then restrict the generic type to.  A way around this is to create a new class that encapsulates both, then restrict on the new class, but that seems like unnecessary extra work and may not always work.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because there would be no difference. `T extends Base` just means that `T` must provide the `Base` interface.  The specific mechanism for how it does so (`extends`, `implements`, `with`) doesn't matter.

Comment: Aha, you're right.  I should have tried it.  Using extends with parameterized types will match cases where your class uses extends, implements, and with.  Thanks!